# Graphics plotting provides distorted and unusable plots with Python 2.7 after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python-2.7, plot

My Python 2.7 code that I've been running in Ubuntu 16.04 does some simple graphics plotting routines that provide distorted and unusable plots now that I've upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. I get no error messages or warnings. I'm NOT running python3 in the new Ubuntu and the version I'm invoking is python version 2.7.15rcq. Any suggestions?

The Python libraries that are imported are:
  scipy
  pylab
  math

and a couple that probably aren't relevant to this plotting problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some details, such as what package are you using for the plotting e.g. matplotlib?

Comment: I don't see anything especially wrong with the formatting of this question and I'm voting to leave it open. Wondering a bit though about the default python and whether you've adjusted things package-wise since the upgrade. Showing your code might be a good idea - you can drop it in a pastebin if it's long.

Comment: Python 3 is the default Python version in Ubuntu 18.04. Python 3 is automatically installed if it doesn't already exist on your system when it is upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Python IDE for scientists (*spyder*) can do inline plotting. To try out this feature open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python2.7 ipython python-matplotlib spyder for Python 2.x in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3 ipython3 python3-matplotlib spyder3 for Python 3.x
```

After the ipython prompt in the IPython console copy/paste the below code and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to run it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
x, y = [-1, 12], [1, 4]  
plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o')
```

[image]

If that works try the following Python code which uses scipy, pylab and math modules.

```
import pylab as plb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp
import math

x=ar([37,69,157,238,274,319,391,495,533,626,1366,1855,2821,3615,4130,4374,6453,6863,7021,
    7951,8646,9656,10464,11400])
y=ar([1.77,1.67,1.65,1.17,1.34,1.46,0.75,1,0.8,1.02,0.65,0.69,0.44,0.44,0.55,0.43,0.75,0.27,0.26,
    0.44,0.04,0.44,0.26,0.04])

n = 24                                  # the number of data
mean = sum(x*y)/n                       # note this correction
sigma = math.sqrt(sum(y*(x-mean)**2)/n) # note this correction

def gaus(x,a,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x)**2/(2*sigma**2))

p0 = [1.2, 4000]
popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=p0) 

plt.plot(x,y,'b+:',label='data')
plt.plot(x,gaus(x,*popt),'ro:',label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Fig. 3 - Fit for Time Constant')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.show()

def gaus(x,a,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x)**2/(2*sigma**2))

p0 = [1.2, 4000]
popt,pcov = curve_fit(gaus,x,y,p0=p0)
```

The output is shown in the below screenshot.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

The output shows this warning:

```
Warning: pylab (numpy and matplotlib) and symbolic math (sympy) are both 
enabled at the same time. Some pylab functions are going to be overrided by   
the sympy module (e.g. plot).
```

... but the plot is output correctly despite this warning message.

In order to eliminate the warning message remove the `import pylab as plb` at line 1 from the code. Clicking the triangular icon to the left of line 1 shows the following syntax checking message.

```
'pylab as plb' imported but unused
```

The syntax checking message is correct. The code outputs exactly the same plot when line 1 is removed. Sometimes it helps to use an IDE when debugging lengthy blocks of code because an IDE has features like syntax checking.